# Get Specific Values from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to get a value from a XML and create this output:

```
OUTPUT1=Question1=No&Question2=Yes
```

My current output is:

```
    Question1=No
    Question2=Yes
```

I don't know the best approach to do this, I'm new to XSLT and I was thinking to store these values into a variable and use them later like:
OUTPUT1=Variable1&Variable2

But even that it is a challenge to me, can someone help me with directions ?

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="processQuestion">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'ADM_1'"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="processQuestion">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'ADM_2'"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="processQuestion">
    <xsl:param name="name"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//x:form/x:add[@name=$name]" mode="process" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:add" mode="process">
    <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>=<xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<transaction xmlns="TransactionDataOfRequest" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <success>true</success>
  <code>0</code>
  <value>
    <form>
      <add name="ADM_1" title="Question 1" type="String" isList="false">No</add>
      <add name="ADM_2" title="Question 2" type="String" isList="false">Yes</add>
    </form>
  </value>
</transaction>
```

Variable

```
    <xsl:variable name="test">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="TransactionDataOfRequest">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="param1" select="'ADM_1'"/>
    <xsl:param name="param2" select="'ADM_2'"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="//x:form/x:add">
      <xsl:if test="@name=$param1">
Question1=<xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="//x:form/x:add">
      <xsl:if test="@name=$param2">
        <xsl:variable name="test">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
Question2=<xsl:copy-of select="$test" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That was my first attempt, in fact I was able to save the value into a variable, but that variable only exist inside that template right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it the simple way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tx="TransactionDataOfRequest">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>OUTPUT1=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="tx:transaction/tx:value/tx:form/tx:add[@name='ADM_1' or @name='ADM_2']">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **example input**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<transaction xmlns="TransactionDataOfRequest" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <success>true</success>
    <code>0</code>
    <value>
    <form>
        <add name="ADM_1" title="Question 1" type="String" isList="false">No</add>
        <add name="XCL_3" title="Question 3" type="String" isList="false">Yes</add>
        <add name="ADM_2" title="Question 2" type="String" isList="false">Yes</add>
    </form>
    </value>
</transaction>
```

produces the result::

```
OUTPUT1=Question 1=No&Question 2=Yes
```

I am not sure if you need to remove the spaces in the original names.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your reply, it's because I don't know the order of questions I might have to combine two questions ie the first with the latest. So I need a way to tell what I need to get. That's why I have processQuestion in the first xslt and the for each with an if as a filter.

Comment: @CelsoCatarinoNeto Where are the values ADM_1 and ADM_2 coming from? Are they supposed to be hard-coded in the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes they come from the XML, they are hardcoded because that's how I select what I want from the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Why store the values in variables? Is there a need for it?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="TransactionDataOfRequest">
<xsl:output method="text" indent='yes'/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:value-of select="for $var in //x:form/x:add return concat(translate($var/@title,' ',''),$var)" separator="&amp;"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('OUTPUT1=',$temp)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio and I'm getting: XslTransformException
---------------------
Expected end of the expression, found '$'.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think VS 2013 .NET 4.5 supports xslt 2.0